# How to add text to the end of a line in a string? - Python

Tags: python

How can I write some text to the end of a line in a multiple-line string in python, without knowing slice numbers? Here's an example:

```
mystring="""
This is a string.
This is the second Line. #How to append to the end of this line, without slicing?
This is the third line."""
```

I hope I'm clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the string is relatively small, I'd use `str.split('\n')` to break it into a list of strings. Then change the string you want, and the join the list:

```
l = mystr.split('\n')
l[2] += ' extra text'
mystr = '\n'.join(l)
```

Also, if you can identify uniquely how the line you want to append to ends, you can use `replace`. For instance, if the line ends with `x`, then you could do

```
mystr.replace('x\n', 'x extra extra stuff\n')
```

Comment: +1 For the general idea, but you can't use append on a string object like that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, strings are immutable so you will have to build a new string.  Use the method `splitlines` on `mystring` object (so that you don't have to explicitly specify the line-end char) and then join them into a new string however you wish.

```
>>> mystring = """
... a
... b
... c"""
>>> print mystring

a
b
c
>>> mystring_lines = mystring.splitlines()
>>> mystring_lines[2] += ' SPAM'
>>> print '\n'.join(mystring_lines)

a
b SPAM
c
```